# Rsync check available

Tags: linux, networking, rsync

Hi i have the following mesh from raspberry pi which is with protocol 802.11s.
In a pi5 with an ip 10.0.0.15 i have video capture who makes files in /home/pi/Desktop, And i need to make an arhive in pi1 with ip address 10.0.0.11 in folder /home/pi/arhive but it must check availability what pi is in range and then to make arhive. 
In the above diagram 5 node must take pictures/video and transfers the data to the available neighbour node and then it transfers to the other available neighbour node. It should choose the best path to transfer the data. Like 5-4-2-1 or 5-4-3-1.

Or if the either of the nodes are unavailable it should redirect the packets to the different node.

For example, in 5-4-2-1 path if node if node 4 is unavailable it should redirect the packets to 5-2-1 if the 2 node is available or should choose the alternative path automatically either 5-4-3-1 or 5-3-1.

[image]